# LUA script that will return false until an elapsed time (of random value between two fixed limits) has passed - and then it returns true?

Tags: lua, scripting

I trying to write a small/simple LUA script that returns false unless enough time has elapsed, when it should return true.

The period of time should be randomly chosen between two constant fixed upper and lower limits (preferably in seconds).

When it has returned true, it needs to start again but with a new random period.

This will be called by another Lua script that will 'run it' every 1 second.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start/playaround with this...

```
-- randt.lua                          
local function randt(min, max, limit)
math.randomseed(math.random(os.time())) -- Works with many calls in a second
local min, max, limit = min or 60, max or 300, limit or 180
local randt = {min, max}
local choosed = math.random(randt[1], randt[2])

print(min, max, limit, choosed) -- debug info

if choosed > limit then
 return false -- over limit
else
 return true  -- under limit
end
   
end

return randt -- For: randt = require('randt') or if require('randt')(1, 80, 40) then ... end
```

Example of use...

```
randt = require('randt')

if randt(1, 60, 45) then
 print('SUCCESS')
else
 print('TRY IT AGAIN')
end
```